# Gradle Maven plugin "install" task does not work with Android library project

Tags: java, android, maven, installation, gradle

I want to install android library project to local maven repository.
Here is *build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
group = "com.example"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
gradle install -i
```

it gets stuck here:

```
Executing task ':project:installTest' due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Starting process 'command 'd:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe''. Working directory: D:\Projects\java\....... Command: d:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe install -r D:\Projects\java\.......\build\apk\project.apk
An attempt to initialize for well behaving parent process finished.
Successfully started process 'command 'd:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe''
> Building > :project:installTest
```

So first thing I noticed is that it's trying for some odd reason to deploy it on a device as APK.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just android-library plugin not compatible with maven plugin?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Edit:** Please refer to the github page (https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin) for the latest instructions and find the correct version to use. The original instructions are not suitable anymore with the latest gradle release.

**Original Post:**

I've modified the maven plugin to be compatible with android library projects. See the project on github: https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin

Configure your android library projects to use it:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'
```

Then you should be able to install aar into your local maven repository using the install task.

Hope this helps, if you find issues with the plugin please let me know on github and I'll fix it.

Comment: How do you configure the groupid, artifactid and version using this plugin?

Comment: That's a very nice solution. I'm using it now in my library project! My only concern is, how would you cope with new updates to Gradle Maven plugin, are you going to keep those in sync?

Comment: Well I didn't need to so far, but if you (or someone else) notice it breaks when using a new gradle release then please open an issue on the github project and I'll release an updated version.

Comment: Works great, and adding in a few parts from step 1 here: https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/, gets it to push sources and javadoc as well.

Comment: I get `org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectInternal.getPluginManager()Lorg/gradle/api/internal/plugins/PluginManagerInternal;` when using this solution

Comment: You are not using the correct version of the plugin, see the github page for the compatibility matrix with gradle. I'll amend my post as well to let other people know.

Answer (score 18):

Elaborating on CyclingSir's answer, I propose to add a separate "installArchives" task. This should also take care of picking up your custom artifacts (e.g. sources).

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

task installArchives(type: Upload) {
  description "Installs the artifacts to the local Maven repository."
  configuration = configurations['archives']
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository url: repositories.mavenLocal().url
    }
  }
}
```

Note that with Gradle Android plugin v0.5.5, `gradle install` still tries to install something on a device.

Comment: Works great! You can use `repositories.mavenLocal().url` instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 11):

There's an easier solution if you don't want to use a custom plugin. Instead, just recreate the install task with a different name. I called it `installArchives`. Add the following code to your `build.gradle`:

```groovy
task installArchives(type: Upload) {
    description "Installs the artifacts to the local Maven repository."
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        configuration = configurations.default
        pom.groupId = 'my.group'
        pom.artifactId = 'my-artifact'
        pom.version = '1.0.0'
    }
}
```

You can now run `gradle installArchives` to install your aar locally.

Comment: Can you modify your task to also generate jars for sources and JavaDoc?

Comment: @JJD This task will only upload the aar (no jars) from the default configuration. I don't believe the Android gradle plugin supports generating JavaDocs or source aars out of the box. Figuring out how to do that would probably warrant its own question.

Comment: While the aar is deployed to the maven repo, the generated pom does not contain the dependencies of the library project.

Comment: I had the same issue as Moritz, however using viphe's approach, everything got uploaded as they should.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE 2014-11-26**

The answer below made sense at the time of writing, when Android Build Tools were at version 0.5.5. It is most likely outdated now and probably does not work anymore.

I have personally switched my projects to use `android-maven-plugin` as described in the answer above, the plugin works fine with the recent versions of Android Build Tools too.

**THE ORIGINAL ANSWER FROM FEBRUARY 2014**

**Publishing as AAR**

If you don't mind using an older version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` (i.e. 0.5.4), you can use the approach described in [this blogpost](http://www.flexlabs.org/2013/06/using-local-aar-android-library-packages-in-gradle-builds). Not that according to [the discussion in adt-dev mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/android.libraryVariants$200.5.4/adt-dev/yZiGE_rCxMQ/XKfilHN0iscJ), this does not work in 0.5.5.

Add the following lines to your `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

// load bundleRelease task
// this will not load the task in 0.5.5
android.libraryVariants

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bundleRelease
        }
    }
}
```

To publish to your local maven repo, call this command:

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

**Publishing as JAR**

If your Android Library does not have custom resources and can be published as JAR, then you can use the following `build.gradle` that works even with 0.5.5.

```
// build JAR file
task androidReleaseJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: assembleRelease) {
    from "$buildDir/classes/release/"
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact androidReleaseJar
        }
    }
}
```

To publish to your local maven repo, call this command:

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

Comment: Maybe you have an anwer on [how to change the `artifactId` while using `maven-publish`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800033/how-to-overwrite-artifactid-for-android-gradle-library-project) ..?

Comment: Is there still no workaround for Android 0.5.5 and `andoroid.libraryVariants`.

Comment: I have personally switched to android-maven-plugin (see the accepted answer) and never looked back at the workaround described in my answer.

Comment: Does not work for me.  I get an error saying "Could not find property 'bundleRelease'"

Comment: The solution proposed in my answer may be outdated now. We are using `android-maven-plugin` in our projects and it works fine for us.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue by defining an upload archive as described here:
[Gradle documentation 52.6.2. Deploying to a Maven repository](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html)

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repository(url: "file://${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository/")
    }
  }
}
```

calling

```
gradle uploadArchives
```

deploys the artefact to the (in my case local) Maven repo. 
I havn't found a simple and more flexible way to specify the local repo's url with e.g. mavenLocal() yet but the above suits my needs.

Comment: Thanks but I asked for `gradle install` not `gradle uploadArchives`, which in my case is used to actually upload artifact to Maven Central. I want to be able to install in my local maven repository before releasing it to Maven Central.

Comment: This is actually not good practice - please refer to [Peter's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21840160/356895).