# How to overwrite artifactId for Android Gradle library project?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, publishing, android-gradle-plugin

I created an Android library project using Android Studio with the following directory structure:

```
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── local.properties
├── settings.gradle
├── FooBar.iml
└── FooBar Library
```

When I want to [publish](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#publishing_maven) the library to my local Maven repository I encounter the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':Foobar Library:publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'MavenLocal'
   > Invalid publication 'maven': 
     artifactId is not a valid Maven identifier ([A-Za-z0-9_\-.]+).
```

Please notice that the folder "FooBar Library" contains a **space**. How can I set the `artifactId` for Gradle so I can **overwrite** the default `artifactId`?

---

Side note: If you are using [`uploadArchives`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N103D7) in favor of `maven-publish` you can rename the `artifactId` setting `archivesBaseName` as follows:

```
archivesBaseName = "foobar-library"
```

Comment: Why not changing the name `Foobar-Library`?

Comment: @khmarbaise There are situations where you cannot change the setup. I believe there should be a way to overwrite the `artifactId` somehow.

Comment: The point is the artifactId identifier has a format which is defined which can't be changed. In Java you have some rules for package names or java class names would you try to change them as well ? Does simply not work.

Comment: @khmarbaise It works for `uploadArchives` so it should work for `maven-publish` as well.