# How to push to local and remote Maven repository using uploadArchives?

Tags: maven, deployment, gradle, build.gradle

I came across `gradle publishToMavenLocal` as part of the ["maven-publish" plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) which installs a build into the local `~/.m2` folder. Since I am still using `gradle uploadArchives` I wonder if there is something similar which would allow to choose between local and remote deployment?

A manual way to configure the local Maven repository is the following:

```groovy
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository url: 'file://' + new File(
                System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath
        }
    }
}

task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)
```

I also came up with the idea that whenever the build is uploaded to the remote repository it is installed to the local repository as well. But I am not sure if it is wanted to automate this - comments are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have applied the `maven` plugin, all you need to do to install to the local Maven repository is to execute `gradle install` (without any further declarations in the build script). Installation can be fine-tuned via `mavenInstaller` (instead of `mavenDeployer` for an external repository).

Comment: Seems as if I missed this - although I should know from using Maven. Thank you.

Comment: Does `task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)` interfere with `gradle install`?

Comment: A project cannot have two tasks with the same name. The `maven` plugin will already add an `install` task, so this task declaration should fail.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I assumed this might be wrong after digest your initial answer. Will have to tidy up my script..

Comment: I did not exclusively ask but could you please update your answer on the fact how the `maven` plugin behaves different in combination with the `android-library` plugin? In my Android library project there is only a `gradle installDebugTest` task which expects a device being connected.

Comment: If you applied the `maven` plugin, there needs to be an `install` task, but I don't know if it works correctly for an Android project.

Comment: I found a discussion here: [Gradle Maven plugin “install” task does not work with Android library project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559932/gradle-maven-plugin-install-task-does-not-work-with-android-library-project)

Comment: An example of specifying the maven artifact indentifiers would be nice. This Q is all over google with a host of conflicting replies including pointing the mavenDeployer directly at .m2.