# How to use an Android gradle library in several projects without having to deploy it to a server?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a utility library, that I'd like to use in several app projects.
I'd like to be able to work on it without having to deploy to a server every time I change something. I need a way to test it in my app before publishing the changes anywhere.

The way I would normally do this is to install the lib to my local maven repository (by local I mean on my dev machine's hard drive), in order to make it visible to the app projects.

Unfortunately, it seems that `gradle install` doesn't work on Android projects (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559932/gradle-maven-plugin-install-task-does-not-work-with-android-library-project)).

So my question is, what's the recommended way to do this and how do most people do? This seems to me as a fairly common use case!

Comment: "Unfortunately, it seems that gradle install doesn't work on Android projects (see this SO question)" -- did you read the accepted answer on that question? I have been using `android-maven-plugin` for months for my CWAC libraries with success.

Comment: Yes I read the accepted answer and was hoping to not depend on a fork of the official maven plugin, made by some unknown person from SO :) I mean, it didn't seem quite right, do you agree?

Comment: Well, in an ideal world, there'd be a more official solution in hand. In an ideal world, I'd have hair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I describe my current workflow. Maybe it helps you, too.

If I develop a library, which targets a special app, I upload a Snapshot build to my local maven repo (upload works). In my app project I reference the Snapshot build. Each time you build the app project Gradle checks for a new Snapshot release. So you definitely use the most current version of your library.

If the library is finished, I upload a finished (no Snapshot) build with a fixed version to my local repository. Later, if I want to extend the library, I increase the version of the library and add the snapshot suffix again.

I'm pretty happy with this workflow. You may want to take a look at one of my [build files](https://github.com/vRallev/android-base/blob/master/Android-Base-Project/android-base/build.gradle). In order to upload a Snapshot build, you only need to add the suffix '-SNAPSHOT' to the version string.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to be what I want to do indeed. However how do you deploy the snapshot build to your local maven repo? Shouldn't `maven install` be used to do that?

Comment: Yes, You should use `maven install`.

Comment: Take a look at the build file. I run `gradle uploadArchives`, which basically does the same.

Comment: Opal: `maven install` does not work with Android projects. Or does it? Have you tried it? Are you saying it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already deploying to the maven local, then you can just add that as a repo source for gradle. At least that's what we did:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not already deploying to the maven local, as stated in the question, because `gradle install` doesn't work.